# Parameter Not In Scope when Compiling LambdaExpression

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm doing a bit of work using reflection and want to create a LambdaExpression that I can run against a `List<T>` collection and intersect with a `HashSet<int>` collection to find any matches.

My problem is that `T` does not implement a common base class or interface, hence the reflection on types and a requirement tp programatically build a Lambda expression.

I'f I knew my types, what I wnat to execute is:

```
List<TestClass> entityList = GetOriginalList();
HashSet<int> idList = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<TestClass> filteredList = entityList.Where(o => idList.Contains(o.Id)).ToList();
```

I started mocking up a way to do this using `LambdaExpression`, but I can't get the thing to compile and can't seem to figure out how to do what it wants (i.e. feed in the variable for the `HashSet<int>`).  My bodged attempt is below, does anyone have any suggestions as to how to get the `LambdaExpression` to compile, and how to actually execute it getting a `List<myObject>` out at the other end?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace PoCDynamicLambda
{
    class Program
    {
        class TestClass
        {
            private int _id;
            private string _value;

            public int Id { get { return this._id; } set { this._id = value; } }
            public string Value { get { return this._value; } set { this._value = value; } }

            public TestClass(int id, string value)
            {
                this._id = id;
                this._value = value;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<TestClass> entityList = new List<TestClass>()
            {
                new TestClass(1, "One"),
                new TestClass(2, "Two"),
                new TestClass(3, "Three")
            };

            HashSet<int> idList = new HashSet<int>() { 2, 3, 5 };

            MethodInfo containsMethod = idList.GetType().GetMethod("Contains");
            ParameterExpression idListParam = Expression.Parameter(idList.GetType(), "idList");
            ParameterExpression objectListParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TestClass), "entityList");
            PropertyInfo idProperty = typeof(TestClass).GetProperty("Id");
            MemberExpression idMember = Expression.Property(objectListParam, idProperty);
            MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(idListParam, containsMethod, idMember);
            LambdaExpression le = Expression.Lambda(methodCall, objectListParam);
            Console.WriteLine(le); // returns {entityList => idList.Contains(entityList.Id)}

            le.Compile(); // Error here
            Console.WriteLine(le.Compile().DynamicInvoke(entityList));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `idList` in the call to `Expression.Lambda`, and supply an argument in the final invoke (`DynamicInvoke` in your example). Or if it is meant to be fixed at {2,3,5}, replace `idList` with an `Expression.Constant`.

Note that if you want to get the performance, you need to use *typed* invoke, not `DynamicInvoke`.

Comment: Wow, you're quick!  I was going to log in tomorrow and see if anyone replied :)

Comment: So, that would be as another ParameterExpression then, right? It is indeed, not a constant in the final version.

Comment: @mnield - you already have the parameter-expression; you just didn't include it in the call to `Lambda`. It should be `Expression.Lambda(methodCall, objectListParam, idList)` (or the other way around); equally, you need to pass in the *actual* list to invoke: `.DynamicInvoke(entityList,idList)`

Comment: OK, yeah.  Got it, thanks!  It now compiles like a charm.  Unfortunately, DynamicInvoke() now chokes and says `Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PoCDynamicLambda.Program+TestClass]' cannot be converted to type 'PoCDynamicLambda.Program+TestClass'.`  I guess one of my types must be incorrect :$